# Do you like this nothingness?

Tags: bug, advertising

I noticed there is no ad showing on askubuntu just now, but I can still upvote it. Is this even a bug? I don't know! But I'm letting you know anyway.

Here is a screenshot:

> [image: A picture showing you can upvote/downvote where an ad should be, but with no ad]

Comment: If you haven't refreshed yet, can you right click it and copy both the image URL and actual URL?

Comment: @Zacharee1 sorry, I already lost it. If it comes back I'll let you know.

Comment: Just to sanity-check: you're not running any filters or ad-blockers, are you?

Comment: This is what happens when I run a Ghostery and/or Privacy Badger.

Comment: @Shog9 httpseverywhere with basically default settings. But I still see many ads on Stack*

Comment: What, you mean you guys can't see the gorgeous tiger in the image?

Comment: @kojiro are you on https or http?

Comment: .I am on https.